# Non-const pointer prefers const T& overload to const T*

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

Suppose I have two overloads of a function

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T&) {
    cout << "f(T&)" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void f(const T*) {
    cout << "f(T*)" << endl;
}
```

Why does `f(new int)` resolves to the `f(const T&)` instead of `f(const T*)`?  Anywhere in the standard talks about this counter-intuitive behavior?

http://ideone.com/kl8NxL

Comment: `f(new int)` resolves to `f(const T&)` with `T` set to `int*`, not with `T` set to `int`. It's as if you are calling a function with the signature.

    `f(int* const&);`

Comment: I knew this part. My question is, why is `f(int* const&)` a better match than `f(const int*)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For overload resolution with template deduction, the first step is to resolve the templates. Then non-template ordering is applied to the results.  In your code the template resolutions are:

```
void f(int * const &)   // 1

void f(int const *)     // 2
```

According to C++14 [over.ics.ref], a reference binding directly to an argument  as in (1) is an *identity conversion* (even if there are added cv-qualifiers).  The binding of `T` to `T const &` is a direct binding, i.e. no temporaries are created and bound.

However, (2) involves a *qualification conversion*. The argument type `int *` must be converted to `const int *` before it matches the function parameter.

The identity conversion is considered a sub-sequence of any non-identity conversion sequence, so (1) wins according to the sub-sequence rule [over.ics.rank]/3.1.1